# animationDidStop method called immediately

Tags: objective-c, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I've never had this issue come up before. my animationDidStop method is being called before the animation actually completes.  animationDidStart gets called first, but then animationDidStop is called immediately after.  I tried to handle this using an animation completion block, but it called the animation completed immediately still.  Anybody run across this before?  I really could use a bit of help.  THANK YOU.

-James

CODE:

```
-(void) runAnimation {

//Create an animation that rotates the tile

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
[animation setDuration:6];
[animation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0]];
[animation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5*M_PI]];
[animation setDelegate:self];
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

[[self.view viewWithTag:100].layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"solutionRotate"];

}

-(void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
{

        if (theAnimation == [[self.view viewWithTag:100].layer animationForKey:@"solutionRotate"]){

            //test
            NSLog (@"test");

    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a bug in your code sample? You add "animateStuff" instead of "animation"

Comment: Have you tried using CATransaction completion block?

Answer (score 4):

If the layer is not part of any layer tree then the animation will end immediately since there is nothing to actually animate on screen. Make sure the animated view is added to a visible view hierarchy.